# Allow non Admin users to modify / edit table

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm working on AppMaker since few week but I got stuck, so I got a very simple question but I can't find any answer.

Is it possible to non admin access user to modify or edit a table on release App? For example, the Hello Data tutorial, if you release a deployments version, a non admin user cannot work with it because he can't modify data. And obviously, I saw nothing on google documentation

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to access levels within the models themselves, such as creating, editing, loading and deleting. App Maker defaults each model so only Admins have all of those access levels. You need to go into each model and change the access levels to suit your needs. Please see the attached picture. If you need different access levels for each of these functions you need to choose 'Advanced'.
[image: App Maker Model Security Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are getting at is you want the public to be able to view and use the app without having to log into google right?

I'm having the same issue. I'd like to have an app completely public useable by anyone with a link without ever having to login to google.

Once your users log into their google account they can see your app when you mark it public or don't restrict access, the unlogged in public cannot see a public app apparently.

Comment: You haven't solved asker's problem. This answer is low quality. I could downvote, but your score isn't quite high at this moment. Be cereful.